# What is the name of this Yahtzee variant with 10 dice?

Tags: identify-this-game, yahtzee

I took a class once where we had to design a handheld game system for a variant of Yahtzee, which I seem to recall being called "Back Yahtzee", however I am unable to confirm this online.

There were two sets of dice and I remember the "Yahtzee" was obtained by getting 10 of the same number and it was called a "big big."
I recall that you could score two things at a time, for example a full house on 5 dice and straight on the other 5.

Does anybody know the name of this game and where I could find the rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it [Double Cameroon](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/868542/double-cameroon). It sees to match.

Comment: Here's another like to the rules: http://www.boardgamecentral.com/rules/double-cameroon-rules.html